# Show field in aura component with condition

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, developer, lightning-development

I would like to show a field (inputEmail) only if another field (emailCc) is not empty. and the show that part with a toggle button if the user needs to fill anything.

cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="emailBcc"             type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="showCc"               type="Boolean" default="False" />


<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showCc}">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form_horizontal slds-form slds-grid" aura:id="cc">
                                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="CC" style="width: 100px;">Cc</label>
                                        <ui:inputEmail class="slds-input" aura:id="emailCc" value="{!v.emailCc}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </aura:if>

 <button class="slds-button" onclick="{!c.toggleCcSection}">Cc</button>
```

controller:

```
toggleCcSection : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showCc", !component.get("v.showCc"));         
}
```

helper:

```
  component.set("v.emailcc",        response.getReturnValue().emailcc);
```

I tried to put defulat="{not(empty(v.emailCc))}" but it's not working.
any idea please how should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 solutions:

1.
You need to wrap the field in `<aura:if>` as below :

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.emailcc))}">

...
</aura:if>
```

Please check the function reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) .

2. <aura:if isTrue="{!OR(not(empty(v.emailcc)),v.showCc)}">
3. try this in doinit - component.set("v.showcc",component.get("v.emailcc").length !== 0)

Comment: thank you for the answer! but this way the button stops working. and also putting this code in attribute default is not working. very weird!

Comment: Putting the condition in default will not work. Can you clarify the exact condition and the button you are trying to hide ?

Comment: Hi Rohit, there is a button which calls above function
<button class="slds-button" onclick="{!c.toggleCcSection}" >Cc</button>

Comment: Got it , basically , you need to show the field on button click OR emailCC field is not empty , right ?

Comment: In that case , just replace <aura:if> with this - <aura:if isTrue="{!OR(not(empty(v.emailcc)),v.showCc)}">

Comment: Hi Rohit, thx for your feedback! it's not working. is there any way to set the value of showcc in conroller to this at the begining in the doinit method => showcc = !not(empty(v.emailcc))
I tried but didnt work

Comment: We cannot use markup in JS. try this in doinit - `component.set("v.showcc",component.get("v.emailcc").length !== 0)`